# How to create a method which accepts strings with format directly as argument?

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, methods, format

I don't know exactly how to put this question. 
I want to create a method like `stringWithFormat:` or `predicateWithFormat:`, i.e. my method accepts argument directly as a string with format specifiers. How can I achieve this?

**E.g.,**

```
-(void) someMethod: (NSString *)str, format;
```

So that I can later call it like:

```
[someObject someMethod:@"String with format %@",anotherString];
```

*This is not in relation to any particular context.*

I was working `predicateWithFormat` with a code similar to:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like myName"];
```

This didn't work, but:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like 'myName'"];
```

worked similar to:

```
NSString *str = @"myName";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@",str];
```

So this means the method is able to understand if the argument given has format specifiers used inside them. I'm curious how can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for methods with variable number of parameters. Methods need to be declared like this:

```
-(void) someMethod: (NSString *)str, ...; // Yes, three dots
```

Inside the method you use macros to extract parameters one by one. The first parameter needs to supply enough information to tell how many other parameters are passed. For example, `stringWithFormat` can tell how many parameters are passed by counting unescaped `%` format specifiers.

```
- (void) someMethod:NSString *)str, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);
    int some_count = /* figure out how many args there are */;
    for( int i = 0; i < some_count; i++ ) {
        value = va_arg(args, <some_type>); // You need to derive the type from the format as well
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the varargs macros `va_start`, `va_end`, etc:

```
-(void) someMethod: (NSString *)fmt, ...
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);    
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:fmt
                                              arguments:va];
    va_end(va);

    // Do thing with string
}
```

The important thing to remember is that vararg parameters lose their type so functions like `printf()` and `[NSString stringWithFormat]` use the format string to help determine how many arguments there are and how each should be interpreted.  If you need a different semantic then you will need to provide this information some how.

Comment: Can you please explain on varargs macros. I'm pretty new to objective-c.

Comment: @Rakesh Varargs aren't Objective-C, they are C.  See this page: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html

Comment: Should the above be [NSString stringWithFormat:reason, va] rather than with the 'arguments' bit listed? I couldn't get this to compile otherwise. Thanks though!

Comment: @TheSenator You are right; it should have been `initWithFormat:arguments:`.  I have fixed it now; thanks.